# Translate RTL to Gate Level Design - Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have the follwing code for sinc3 filter in verilog. How should produce a gate level syntheis of the follwoing design in Vivado? Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module sinc3
(input mclk1, /* used to clk filter */
input reset, /* used to reset filter */
input mdata1, /* input data to be filtered */

output reg [15:0] DATA, /* filtered output*/
output reg data_en,
input [15:0] dec_rate
);

/* Data is read on negative clk edge */
reg [36:0] ip_data1;
reg [36:0] acc1;
reg [36:0] acc2;
reg [36:0] acc3;
reg [36:0] acc3_d2;
reg [36:0] diff1;
reg [36:0] diff2;
reg [36:0] diff3;
reg [36:0] diff1_d;
reg [36:0] diff2_d;

reg [15:0] word_count;

reg word_clk;
reg enable;

/*Perform the Sinc action*/
always @ (mdata1)
if(mdata1==0)
    ip_data1 <= 37'd0;
    /* change 0 to a -1 for twos complement */
else
    ip_data1 <= 37'd1;

/*Accumulator (Integrator)
Perform the accumulation (IIR) at the speed of the modulator.
Z = one sample delay MCLKOUT = modulators conversion bit rate */

always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
    begin
    /* initialize acc registers on reset*/
        acc1 <= 37'd0;
        acc2 <= 37'd0;
        acc3 <= 37'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
    /*perform accumulation process */
        acc1 <= acc1 + ip_data1;
        acc2 <= acc2 + acc1;
        acc3 <= acc3 + acc2;
    end
end

/*decimation stage (MCLKOUT/WORD_CLK) */
always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
        word_count <= 16'd0;
    else
    begin
        if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
            word_count <= 16'd0;
        else
            word_count <= word_count + 16'b1;
    end
end

always @ ( negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
if ( reset )
    word_clk <= 1'b0;
else
begin
    if ( word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b1;
    else if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b0;
    end
end

/*Differentiator (including decimation stage)
Perform the differentiation stage (FIR) at a lower speed.
Z = one sample delay WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk, posedge reset)
begin
    if(reset)
    begin
        acc3_d2 <= 37'd0;
        diff1_d <= 37'd0;
        diff2_d <= 37'd0;
        diff1 <= 37'd0;
        diff2 <= 37'd0;
        diff3 <= 37'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
        diff1 <= acc3 - acc3_d2;
        diff2 <= diff1 - diff1_d;
        diff3 <= diff2 - diff2_d;
        acc3_d2 <= acc3;
        diff1_d <= diff1;
        diff2_d <= diff2;
    end
end

/* Clock the Sinc output into an output register
WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk )
begin
    case ( dec_rate )
        16'd32:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[15:0] == 16'h8000) ? 16'hFFFF : {diff3[14:0], 1'b0};
        end
        16'd64:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[18:2] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[17:2];
        end
        16'd128:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[21:5] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[20:5];
        end
        16'd256:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[23:8];
        end
        16'd512:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[27:11] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[26:11];
        end
        16'd1024:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[30:14] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[29:14];
        end
        16'd2048:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[33:17] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[32:17];
        end
        16'd4096:begin
        DATA <= (diff3[36:20] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[35:20];
        end
        default:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[23:8];
        end
    endcase
end

/* Synchronize Data Output*/
always@ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
    if ( reset )
    begin
        data_en <= 1'b0;
        enable <= 1'b1;
    end
    else
    begin
        if ( (word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1) && enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b1;
            enable <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if ( (word_count == dec_rate - 1)  && ~enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b0;
            enable <= 1'b1;
        end
        else
            data_en <= 1'b0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

Xilinx Vivado documentation provides generalities and details related to FPGA synthesis.

There are two ways to use Vivado: project and non-project mode. Use project mode if you are unfamiliar with Vivado, and project mode for a more powerful, flexible, re-usable, configuration controlled build process.

Xilinx doc UG 888
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_1/ug888-vivado-design-flows-overview-tutorial.pdf

provides an overview on using Vivado. It contains links to other Vivado introductory level docs.

See 'Lab 2: Using the Project Design Flow' for a tutorial which walks you through step by step the process of creating and building a new project.  It includes setting up a project, adding files, adding constraints, synthesis, place & route, bit file generation, and analyzing the design at points along the way.  Instructions are provided for Windows and Linux.

After the project is set up, click the button "Run Synthesis" in Project Manager section of the project GUI.

[image]

After synthesis, the edif netlist is bundled in a Xilinx container called a .dcp (design checkpoint) file.

A design checkpoint (DCP) is a file used by the Vivado Design Suite that represents a snapshot of a design at any stage of the design process. The snapshot includes the netlist, constraints and implementation results

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does it provide a gate level design after running the synthesis? Or do I need to provide a .xdc file?

Comment: Vivado Synthesis produces an edif format netlist containing Xilinx primatives for the device family and specific device targeted. That .edif file contains instances of Slices, CLBs, RAMs bufg's and other technology and vendor dependent primitives in the netlist. The edif netlist is not an RTL model.  It does not contain individual instances of logic gates or flip-flops. Dot xdc files are used to specify constraints to the build process (synthesis and place & route). Some examples of constrains are clock constraints, and false path constraints